# Navigation with sub menus

Tags: jquery

I learn about Jquery and need a little help with menu witch have a few sub menus for link in primary menu. My code display all sub menus on click, not only one for link on witch I clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sub-menu").hide();
    $(".menu-primary_menu-container li").has("ul").children("a").append("<span> + </span>");
    $(".sub-menu").parent('li').click(function() {
        $(".sub-menu").toggle("slow", function() {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                $("span").text('-');
            } else {
                $("span").text('+');
            }
        });
    });

 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>Item2a</li>
      <li>Item2b</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item3
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>Item3a</li>
      <li>Item3b</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Link witch contains a sub menu, have "+" symbol, and then user can click on "+" for display sub menu. On "-" click, sub menu is invisible.

Comment: Your jQuery selectors do not correspond to the classes in the HTML you provided.

Comment: I know. It's so long... Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery `addClass` to solve the problem!

Use as `addClass("show")` or `removeClass("show")`!